# How to parse IP address into IP number in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ip

What would be the easiest way to take a string containing either IPv4 or IPv6 address and get the IP number?

Comment: The IP… number? What exactly are you looking for? A `data IP4 = IP4 Word8 Word8 Word8 Word8`, or something for C libraries?

Comment: E.g. "134.244.11.55" and get 2264140599

I also need to do that for IPv6.

Comment: So you want a 32 bit integer for IPv4 and a 128 bit integer for IPv6? Or I guess just an `Integer`, I don't think 128 bit fixed width integers are in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a copy-ready solution:

```
module Program where

import Data.IP

ipToOcts :: IP -> [Int]
ipToOcts (IPv4 ip) = fromIPv4 ip
ipToOcts (IPv6 ip) = fromIPv6b ip

ipToInteger :: IP -> Integer
ipToInteger =
    sum . map (\(n,o) -> toInteger o * 256 ^ n) . zip [0..] . reverse . ipToOcts

ipStringToInteger :: String -> Integer
ipStringToInteger = ipToInteger . read
```

Example calls:

```
ipStringToInteger "134.244.11.55"
ipStringToInteger "2001:db8:00:00:00:00:00:01"
```

You need the *iproute* package for that:

```
cabal install iproute
```

Answer (score 2):

`Data.IP` has `IPv4` and `IPv6` types which support parsing from strings, as well as functions for converting them into lists of `Int` values.

```
> fromIPv4 . read "192.0.0.1"
[192,0,0,1]
> fromIPv6b . read "2001:0db8::1"
[32,1,13,184,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Once you have the list, you can fold it to a single integer if you like:

```
> import Data.List
> foldl' (\acc octet -> 256*acc + fromIntegral octet) 0 [192,0,0,1]
3221225473
```

(Since both `fromIPv4` and `fromIPv6` return `[Int]` values, `fromIntegeral` ensures that the fold can return an `Integer`.)

However, consider whether you actually *need* a single integer. Any API you have is really going to be concerned with the individual bytes in the correct order. Other than serializing an address to a binary file, you probably don't even need that.

Answer (score 1):

2018 was released [ip](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ip-1.5.1/docs/Net-IP.html) package, which is very convenient for the purpose.

**Decode**

```
λ> import Net.IP
λ> :set -XOverloadedStrings
λ> decode "127.0.0.1"
Just (ipv4 127 0 0 1)
λ> decode "2a02:2450:dd1f:0:7646:a0ff:fe91:67b1"
Just (ipv6 0x2a02 0x2450 0xdd1f 0x0000 0x7646 0xa0ff 0xfe91 0x67b1)
```

**Encode**

```
λ> encode (ipv4 127 0 0 1)
"127.0.0.1"
λ> encode (ipv6 0x2a02 0x2450 0xdd1f 0x0000 0x7646 0xa0ff 0xfe91 0x67b1)
"2a02:2450:dd1f::7646:a0ff:fe91:67b1
```

The [package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ip-1.5.1/docs/Net-IPv4.html#g:4) provides [Attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.2.2/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#t:Parser) integration.